# IText reading PDF like pdftotext -layout?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdftotext

Im looking for the easiest way to implement a java solution which is quiet similar to the output of

```
pdftotext -layout FILE
```

on linux machines. (And of course it should be cheap as well)

I just tried some code snippets of IText, PDFBox and PDFTextStream. The most accurate solution so far is PDFTextStream which uses the VisualOutputTarget to get a great representation of my file.

So my column layout is recognized correct and I'm able to work with it.
But there should be also a solution for IText, or?

Every easy snippet I found produces plain ordered strings which are a mess (mess up row/column/lines). Is there any solution which might be easier and may not involve a own Strategy? Or is there a open Source strategy which i can use?

// I followed the instructions of mkl and have written and own strategy object as follows:

```
package com.test.pdfextractiontest.itext;

import ...


public class MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy implements TextExtractionStrategy {

    /** set to true for debugging */
    static boolean DUMP_STATE = false;

    /** a summary of all found text */
    private final List<TextChunk> locationalResult = new ArrayList<TextChunk>();


    public MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy() {
    }


    @Override
    public void beginTextBlock() {
    }


    @Override
    public void endTextBlock() {
    }

    private boolean startsWithSpace(final String str) {
        if (str.length() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return str.charAt(0) == ' ';
    }


    private boolean endsWithSpace(final String str) {
        if (str.length() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return str.charAt(str.length() - 1) == ' ';
    }

    private List<TextChunk> filterTextChunks(final List<TextChunk> textChunks, final TextChunkFilter filter) {
        if (filter == null) {
            return textChunks;
        }

        final List<TextChunk> filtered = new ArrayList<TextChunk>();
        for (final TextChunk textChunk : textChunks) {
            if (filter.accept(textChunk)) {
                filtered.add(textChunk);
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    }


    protected boolean isChunkAtWordBoundary(final TextChunk chunk, final TextChunk previousChunk) {
        final float dist = chunk.distanceFromEndOf(previousChunk);

        if (dist < -chunk.getCharSpaceWidth() || dist > chunk.getCharSpaceWidth() / 2.0f) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public String getResultantText(final TextChunkFilter chunkFilter) {
        if (DUMP_STATE) {
            dumpState();
        }

        final List<TextChunk> filteredTextChunks = filterTextChunks(this.locationalResult, chunkFilter);
        Collections.sort(filteredTextChunks);

        final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        TextChunk lastChunk = null;
        for (final TextChunk chunk : filteredTextChunks) {

            if (lastChunk == null) {
                sb.append(chunk.text);
            } else {
                if (chunk.sameLine(lastChunk)) {

                    if (isChunkAtWordBoundary(chunk, lastChunk) && !startsWithSpace(chunk.text)
                            && !endsWithSpace(lastChunk.text)) {
                        sb.append(' ');
                    }
                    final Float dist = chunk.distanceFromEndOf(lastChunk)/3;
                    for(int i = 0; i<Math.round(dist); i++) {
                        sb.append(' ');
                    }
                    sb.append(chunk.text);
                } else {
                    sb.append('\n');
                    sb.append(chunk.text);
                }
            }
            lastChunk = chunk;
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

eturn a String with the resulting text.
         */
        @Override
        public String getResultantText() {

```
        return getResultantText(null);

    }

    private void dumpState() {
        for (final TextChunk location : this.locationalResult) {
            location.printDiagnostics();

            System.out.println();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void renderText(final TextRenderInfo renderInfo) {
        LineSegment segment = renderInfo.getBaseline();
        if (renderInfo.getRise() != 0) { 

            final Matrix riseOffsetTransform = new Matrix(0, -renderInfo.getRise());
            segment = segment.transformBy(riseOffsetTransform);
        }
        final TextChunk location =
                new TextChunk(renderInfo.getText(), segment.getStartPoint(), segment.getEndPoint(),
                        renderInfo.getSingleSpaceWidth(),renderInfo);
        this.locationalResult.add(location);
    }

    public static class TextChunk implements Comparable<TextChunk> {
        /** the text of the chunk */
        private final String text;
        /** the starting location of the chunk */
        private final Vector startLocation;
        /** the ending location of the chunk */
        private final Vector endLocation;
        /** unit vector in the orientation of the chunk */
        private final Vector orientationVector;
        /** the orientation as a scalar for quick sorting */
        private final int orientationMagnitude;

        private final TextRenderInfo info;

        private final int distPerpendicular;

        private final float distParallelStart;

        private final float distParallelEnd;
        /** the width of a single space character in the font of the chunk */
        private final float charSpaceWidth;

        public TextChunk(final String string, final Vector startLocation, final Vector endLocation,
                final float charSpaceWidth,final TextRenderInfo ri) {
            this.text = string;
            this.startLocation = startLocation;
            this.endLocation = endLocation;
            this.charSpaceWidth = charSpaceWidth;

            this.info = ri;

            Vector oVector = endLocation.subtract(startLocation);
            if (oVector.length() == 0) {
                oVector = new Vector(1, 0, 0);
            }
            this.orientationVector = oVector.normalize();
            this.orientationMagnitude =
                    (int) (Math.atan2(this.orientationVector.get(Vector.I2), this.orientationVector.get(Vector.I1)) * 1000);

            final Vector origin = new Vector(0, 0, 1);
            this.distPerpendicular = (int) startLocation.subtract(origin).cross(this.orientationVector).get(Vector.I3);

            this.distParallelStart = this.orientationVector.dot(startLocation);
            this.distParallelEnd = this.orientationVector.dot(endLocation);
        }

        public Vector getStartLocation() {
            return this.startLocation;
        }


        public Vector getEndLocation() {
            return this.endLocation;
        }


        public String getText() {
            return this.text;
        }

        public float getCharSpaceWidth() {
            return this.charSpaceWidth;
        }

        private void printDiagnostics() {
            System.out.println("Text (@" + this.startLocation + " -> " + this.endLocation + "): " + this.text);
            System.out.println("orientationMagnitude: " + this.orientationMagnitude);
            System.out.println("distPerpendicular: " + this.distPerpendicular);
            System.out.println("distParallel: " + this.distParallelStart);
        }


        public boolean sameLine(final TextChunk as) {
            if (this.orientationMagnitude != as.orientationMagnitude) {
                return false;
            }
            if (this.distPerpendicular != as.distPerpendicular) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }


        public float distanceFromEndOf(final TextChunk other) {
            final float distance = this.distParallelStart - other.distParallelEnd;
            return distance;
        }

        public float myDistanceFromEndOf(final TextChunk other) {
            final float distance = this.distParallelStart - other.distParallelEnd;
            return distance;
        }


        @Override
        public int compareTo(final TextChunk rhs) {
            if (this == rhs) {
                return 0; // not really needed, but just in case
            }

            int rslt;
            rslt = compareInts(this.orientationMagnitude, rhs.orientationMagnitude);
            if (rslt != 0) {
                return rslt;
            }

            rslt = compareInts(this.distPerpendicular, rhs.distPerpendicular);
            if (rslt != 0) {
                return rslt;
            }

            return Float.compare(this.distParallelStart, rhs.distParallelStart);
        }

        private static int compareInts(final int int1, final int int2) {
            return int1 == int2 ? 0 : int1 < int2 ? -1 : 1;
        }


        public TextRenderInfo getInfo() {
            return this.info;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void renderImage(final ImageRenderInfo renderInfo) {
        // do nothing
    }


    public static interface TextChunkFilter {

        public boolean accept(TextChunk textChunk);
    }


}
```

As you can see most is the same as the original class. i just added this :

```
                final Float dist = chunk.distanceFromEndOf(lastChunk)/3;
                for(int i = 0; i<Math.round(dist); i++) {
                    sb.append(' ');
                }
```

to the getResultantText Method to extend the gaps with spaces.
But here is the problem:

the distance seems to be inaccurate or inexact. the result looks like

[image: this:] this:

does anyone have an idea how to calculate a better or  value for the distance? i think its because the original font type is ArialMT and my editor is in courier, but to work with this sheet its recommended that i can split the table on the correct place to get my data. thats difficult due the floating start and end of an value usw.

:-/

Comment: That should be fairly easy to implement by copying `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` and changing its method `getResultantText(TextChunkFilter)` a bit. Unfortunately necessary data are private in that class. Thus, deriving from it won't work (without reflection, that is).

Comment: mhh i just tried the standard LocationTextExtractionStrategy and is just a mess too :-X , first of all everything is in reverse, its full of whitespaces on wrong places, but okay... its not messed up in line ordering. :D

Comment: *everything is in reverse* - that would surprise, it explicitly orders. Or do you use some RTL writing? *full of whitespaces on wrong places* - I would assume there are too few whitespaces to represent the original formatting, but too many? Can you share the PDF file in question?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Some classified data ;) But i got it working normally now,... it was just an old version of IText in our Sonatype nexus. But now how get I more spaces between text chunks if they are on a same line and are indented?

Comment: As mentioned you have to edit your copy of `LocationTextExtractionStrategy`, more exactly its method `getResultantText(TextChunkFilter)`, to not only insert a single space for chunks on the same line separated by empty space; instead the number of spaces needs to fill a large enough gap.

Comment: thanks mkl, i did it like you said and have now a little more work to do and didn't get it by myself till now. any new idea ? ;-) thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your approach inserting spaces like this

```
            final Float dist = chunk.distanceFromEndOf(lastChunk)/3;
            for(int i = 0; i<Math.round(dist); i++) {
                sb.append(' ');
            }
```

is that it assumes that the current position in the `StringBuffer` exactly corresponds to the end of `lastChunk` assuming a character width width of 3 user space units. This needs not be the case, generally each addition of characters destroys such a former correspondence. E.g. these two lines have way different widths when using a proportional font:

> ililili
>
> MWMWMWM

while in a `StringBuffer` they occupy the same length.

Thus, you have to look where `chunk` starts **in relation to the left page border** and add spaces to the buffer accordingly.

Furthermore your code completely ignores free space at the start of lines.

Your results should improve if you replace the original method `getResultantText(TextChunkFilter` by this code instead:

```
public String getResultantText(TextChunkFilter chunkFilter){
    if (DUMP_STATE) dumpState();
    
    List<TextChunk> filteredTextChunks = filterTextChunks(locationalResult, chunkFilter);
    Collections.sort(filteredTextChunks);

    int startOfLinePosition = 0;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    TextChunk lastChunk = null;
    for (TextChunk chunk : filteredTextChunks) {

        if (lastChunk == null){
            insertSpaces(sb, startOfLinePosition, chunk.distParallelStart, false);
            sb.append(chunk.text);
        } else {
            if (chunk.sameLine(lastChunk))
            {
                if (isChunkAtWordBoundary(chunk, lastChunk))
                {
                    insertSpaces(sb, startOfLinePosition, chunk.distParallelStart, !startsWithSpace(chunk.text) && !endsWithSpace(lastChunk.text));
                }
                
                sb.append(chunk.text);
            } else {
                sb.append('\n');
                startOfLinePosition = sb.length();
                insertSpaces(sb, startOfLinePosition, chunk.distParallelStart, false);
                sb.append(chunk.text);
            }
        }
        lastChunk = chunk;
    }

    return sb.toString();       
}

void insertSpaces(StringBuffer sb, int startOfLinePosition, float chunkStart, boolean spaceRequired)
{
    int indexNow = sb.length() - startOfLinePosition;
    int indexToBe = (int)((chunkStart - pageLeft) / fixedCharWidth);
    int spacesToInsert = indexToBe - indexNow;
    if (spacesToInsert < 1 && spaceRequired)
        spacesToInsert = 1;
    for (; spacesToInsert > 0; spacesToInsert--)
    {
        sb.append(' ');
    }
}

public float pageLeft = 0;
public float fixedCharWidth = 6;
```

`pageLeft` is the coordinate of the left page border. The strategy does not know it and, therefore, must be told explicitly; in many cases, though, 0 is the correct value.

Alternatively one could use the minimum `distParallelStart` value of all chunks. This would cut off the left margin but would not require you to inject the exact left page border value.

`fixedCharWidth` is the assumed character width. Depending on the writing in the PDF in question a different value might be more apropos. In your case a value of 3 seems to be better than my 6.

There still is a lot of room for improvement in this code. E.g.

- It assumes that there are no text chunks spanning multiple table columns. This assumption very often is correct, but I have seen weird PDFs in which the normal inter-word spacing has been implemented using separate text chunks at some offset but the inter-column spacing was represented by a single space character in a single chunk (spanning the end of one column and the start of the next)! The width of that space character has been manipulated by the word-spacing setting of the PDF graphics state.
- It ignores different amounts of vertical space.