# C#(Asp.net) Convert Pdf to txt file? keeping the pdf alignment (spaces and padding in txt file should be same as pdf file)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext, syncfusion

**itextsharp** and **pdfbox** 
in both i am able to extract the text character, but there alignment is not same as pdf file alignment,(margin left,top etc)

How can i keep the pdf alignment in txt file also?

Comment: The `LayoutTextExtractionStrategy` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46585997/1729265) might give you a bit of what you are looking for. That you hardly will get more, should be clear from  @Bruno's answer.

Comment: As you've meanwhile revisited your question, have you had a look at the `LayoutTextExtractionStrategy`?

Comment: You should accept my answer instead of posting a new, duplicate question that gets closed and deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've experienced when experimenting with both iText and PdfBox, you are asking something that is impossible because of a mismatch between the way the Portable Document Format defines a layout and the way layout is established in the plain text format.

- In `.txt` files, alignment, indentation, spacing,... is achieved using white space characters, such as spaces (), newline characters (`/n`). and tabs (`/t`).
- In `.pdf` files, single space characters are often used in-between words, but when more than one space is needed, or in cases when word-spacing is optimized for a better reading experience, you'll see that absolute positioning is preferred over using space characters. The `\n` in a content stream isn't perceived as a new line for the content, but the concept of a new line exists through new line operators. The concept of a tab doesn't exist at all in PDF; absolute positioning using `(x, y)` coordinates is used instead.

Your expectation that a conversion process from PDF to TXT could somehow solve this syntactical mismatch is endearing, but it starts from an assumption that is totally wrong: you'd need absolute positioning functionality in the plain text format, and that functionality simply isn't there. The answer to your question is that there is no answer.