# Read Column vise data from pdf file in C# and insert to sql table based on that column name

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, extract

I want to Read Column vise data from a PDF file using C# and insert to table based on corresponding column.

Here with attached sample pdf file for your reference. Please any one help to achieve the solution.

[image: Sample PDF file]

**--UPDATE--**

I have tried using PDF library [iTextSharp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/). I have tried method of `PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage`. It will help to extract the all text from pdf file, but I was not able to get the data like row and column wise.

Comment: What have you tried? what research have you done to try to solve your problem? Normally, questions are asked after a user has tried to figure out the problem for themselves first.

Comment: Which pdf library do you use?

Comment: @Chillie  **iTextSharp** pdf library i was tried method of _PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage_. it will help to extract the all text from pdf file. but not able to get the data like row and column vise.

Comment: @mkl **iTextSharp**

Comment: Have you tried something along the lines of what is explained for itext and java in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24911617/1729265)?

Comment: @mkl  No.. I tried only with C#. Not in Java.

Comment: I don't mean trying Java, I mean trying the *idea* outlined in that answer which can as easily be done in c#.

Comment: The equivalent C# `LayoutTextExtractionStrategy` class can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46585997/1729265).